# Using d3 SVG Scale without translate

Tags: javascript, svg, scale, d3.js

I'm trying to use the scale() transform in SVG and d3.  I understand it works by increasing the coordinate scale, but it seems to also be translating my object.  When I have a rectangle located at (100,100) and I do a scale(2), the rectangle doubles in size and moves to (0,0).  How do I get it to stop moving from (100,100) to (0,0) while scaling.  The following is my code:

```
    var mysvg = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .attr("class","mylist");  

    var node = mysvg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(mydata)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class","node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.xpos + "," + d.ypos + ")"; });         

    node.append("rect")
        .attr("width",tileWidth)
        .attr("height",tileWidth)
        .attr("fill","orange")
        .attr("rx",10)
        .attr("ry",10);

    node.append("text")
        .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(" + tileWidth/2 + "," + tileWidth/2 +")" })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", ".3em")
        .attr("font-family","serif")
        .text(function(d) { return d.symbol; });

    node.on("mouseover",function(){ d3.select(this).transition().attr("transform","scale(1.2)") });
    node.on("mouseout",function(){ d3.select(this).transition().attr("transform","scale(1)") });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are overriding the original `translate(" + d.xpos + "," + d.ypos + ")`.

I think the easiest way to work around this would be adding a parent `g` and translating that, such as...

```
var mysvg = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .attr("class","mylist");  

    var parent = mysvg.selectAll("g.parent")
        .data(mydata)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class","parent")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.xpos + "," + d.ypos + ")"; });      

    var node = mysvg.selectAll("g.parent")
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class","node")
     });         

    node.append("rect")
        .attr("width",tileWidth)
        .attr("height",tileWidth)
        .attr("fill","orange")
        .attr("rx",10)
        .attr("ry",10);

    node.append("text")
        .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(" + tileWidth/2 + "," + tileWidth/2 +")" })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", ".3em")
        .attr("font-family","serif")
        .text(function(d) { return d.symbol; });

    node.on("mouseover",function(){ d3.select(this).transition().attr("transform","scale(1.2)") });
    node.on("mouseout",function(){ d3.select(this).transition().attr("transform","scale(1)") });
```

Comment: Can you add a complete example (JSFiddle etc), please?

Comment: @IonicăBizău you can create it yourself and contact me if you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 5):

A general solution to scale without a translation can be found here:
[Scaling Around a Center Point](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Transforming_the_Coordinate_System#Technique%3a_Scaling_Around_a_Center_Point)

Idea:

```
translate(-centerX*(factor-1), -centerY*(factor-1))
scale(factor)
```